# Exception while passing enum value to stored procedure using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum Group
{
        Services = 1,
        Dev = 2,
        Support = 3
}
```

I am using it in a model

```
public class Invoice
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Group? Group { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am calling a stored procedure using the above model class:

```
public ... method(Group grp)
 var Details = this.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Invoice>("spname @ID,@MyDate,@Name,@Group,
 ......
                    new SqlParameter("Group", grp),
                    ).ToList();
```

Group is of `int` type in SQL Server.

I get an exception:

> Error converting nvarchar to int

in case when there is value in the `grp` parameter

I get exception when null is there in parameter that enum should be nullable type..but I have made it i,e `Group?`

The stored procedure itself is working correctly in database using execute command.

Comment: Something missing here; you claim the exception occurs when you use null, but the code you posted has `int grp` in the method signature where the sp call is and int cannot be null

Comment: What is type of parameter for group in your SP?

Comment: @CaiusJard apologies wiill update

Comment: @ManojKumarRai int

Comment: @CaiusJard you edit made it clear now. I think you need to cast grp to int.

Comment: new SqlParameter("Group", (int)grp) ??

Comment: I have added a way as an answer.

Comment: You can't cast a nullable something to an int that way, nor can you convert it as per manoj answer. You have to add code to deal with the case where it's null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SqlParameter sqp = null;
if(grp.HasValue)
  sqp=new SqlParameter("Group", grp.Value)
else
  sqp=new SqlParameter("Group", DBNull.Value)
...
```

Then use sqp in your call to query

Why this complexity? Well.. your grp is type Group? and hence can be null but there isn't a good single line way of converting it to either an int (not nullable) or null (nullable)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new SqlParameter("Group", grp)
```

as

```
   if(grp.HasValue)
   {
      new SqlParameter("Group", Convert.ToInt32(grp.Value));
   }
   else
   {
     new SqlParameter("Group", DBNull.Value);
   }
```

should work.

Comment: What kind of null int will that result in if grp doesn't have a value?

Comment: I just gave a quick example on how to convert enum to int. Obviously handling of null value should be added.