# How to map/populate enum type to integer value from stored proc EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, enums

I have model class with enum

```
public enum Group
{
        Services = 1,
        Dev = 2,
        Support = 3
}

public class Invoice
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Group? Group { get; set; }
}
```

Retrieving using below method

```
public ... method(Group grp)
 var Details = this.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Invoice>("spname @ID,@MyDate,@Name,@Group,
 ............"
                    new SqlParameter("Group", grp),
                    ).ToList();
```

My Stored Procedure is returning a integer value in `group` in sql server execute sp command but the `Group` is null when it gets bind to `Details`.How can map integer to enum?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception while passing enum value to stored procedure using Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396682/exception-while-passing-enum-value-to-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-6)

Comment: It´s hard to understand what your code actually does as it doesn´t even compile because it´s too simplified. I can´t even see an "sp command".

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am calling sp through ef..and it returns a integer value how to map to enum

Comment: @Guy no its not duplicate

Comment: Can´t you just cast the integer you recieve to your enum?

Comment: Your question is asking why the stored procedure is returning null, but you haven't shown us the stored procedure.